# Data associations- classes are not retrieving data of associated class

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 2 classes, Albums and Artists.  Albums can have many Artists and Artists can be in many Albums.  I have navigation properties setup for both view model classes and the method that retrieves the data from the database ensures to include the associative data.  Below are the classes and methods.  When calling the Index or Details action both show that the Artists property has a count of zero.  It should be at 1 artist. Not sure what I am missing.

```cs
public class AlbumController : Controller
    {
         Manager m = new Manager();
        // GET: Album
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var allAlbums = m.AlbumGetAll();
            return View(allAlbums);
        }

        // GET: Album/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var album = m.AlbumGetById(id);
            return View(album);
        }
}
```

```cs
public class AlbumWithDetailViewModel:AlbumBaseViewModel
   {
      public AlbumWithDetailViewModel()
      {
         Artists = new List<ArtistBaseViewModel>();
         Tracks = new List<TrackBaseViewModel>();
      }

      public IEnumerable<ArtistBaseViewModel> Artists { get; set; }
      public IEnumerable<TrackBaseViewModel> Tracks { get; set; }
   }
```

```cs
public class ArtistWithDeatilViewModel:ArtistBaseViewModel
   {
      public ArtistWithDeatilViewModel()
      {
         Albums = new List<AlbumBaseViewModel>();
      }
      public IEnumerable<AlbumBaseViewModel> Albums { get; set; }
   }
```

```cs
///////////// Album Methods /////////////
      public IEnumerable<AlbumWithDetailViewModel> AlbumGetAll()
      {

         return mapper.Map<IEnumerable<AlbumWithDetailViewModel>>(ds.Albums.OrderBy(a => a.Name));
      }

      public AlbumWithDetailViewModel AlbumGetById(int id)
      {
         return mapper.Map<AlbumWithDetailViewModel>(ds.Albums.Include("Artists").SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == id));
      }
```

Comment: It looks like you are using AutoMapper or similar?  The problem is likely with your AutoMapper configuration.  Have you checked the results from your LINQ queries, prior to mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was related to a change I made to my design model classes. Once I removed the sample data from my tables and reloaded them the associations worked.